# How to retrieve an array from Joomla session table

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api, session

I added the data to Joomla session as:

```
$cart['items'][] = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Laptop');
$cart['items'][] = array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Tablet');
$session->set('cart', $cart);
```

If I want to retrieve the data and use

```
$cart_result = $session->get('cart');
echo $cart_result;
```

I get only the word **Array**. How can I retrieve the data properly? Please write different options: for whole array and single row. I don't mean `echo print_r($cart_result, TRUE)`

Comment: Could you add the result to your question you get when you use `$session->get('cart', $cart);`? Note the `get->` instead of `set->`

Comment: The question is updated

Comment: Sorry, I meant `var_dump($session->get('cart', $cart));`. This should display an array of results for you. Please copy the results you see and I'll compile an answer for you

Comment: `array(1) { ["items"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["name"]=> string(6) "Laptop" } [1]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(2) ["name"]=> string(6) "Tablet" } } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpler solution is:

```
foreach($cart_result['items'] as $result) {
    echo $result['id'];
    echo $result['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've some up with the following which will hopefully work for you.

So firstly, you need to define the session variable like so:

```
$cart_result = $session->get('cart');
```

Then you will need to iterate though the array that gets returned, like so:

```
$keys = array_keys($cart_result);
$count = count(array_shift(array_values($cart_result)));

for ($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++) 
{
    $results = array();
    foreach ($keys as $key) 
    {
        $results[$key] = $cart_result[$key][$i];
    }

    foreach ($results as $result)
    {
        echo $result['id'];
        echo $result['name'];
    }
}
```

From the dump you provide in your comment, this will output the following:

```
1 Laptop
2 Tablet
```

#### Update (credit goes to @stckvrw)

For PHP 5.4+ where strict errors will be thrown, replace:

```
$count = count(array_shift(array_values($cart_result)));
```

with:

```
$tmp = array_values($cart_result);
$count = count(array_shift($tmp));
```

Comment: Yes, it displays what I need but there is also the error: **Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in ... line #** `$count = count(array_shift(array_values($cart_result)));`

Comment: Yup, you simply need to disable strict error reporting which most people do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983286/disabling-strict-standards-in-php-5-4

Comment: Is there some way to eliminate the cause of the error?

Comment: I'm not a massive PHP expert but it's due to `array_shift`. The iteration may need to be rewritten a little

Comment: I've found: `$tmp = array_values($cart_result);$count = count(array_shift($tmp));` You may update your answer