# Join data from session with sql-query and display in module

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, module, joomla-api, session

I'm developing a module for displaying products that are added to Joomla session. The products are being added to the session by using the code:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$input = $app->input;
$itemid = $input->get('itemid');
$quan = $input->get('quan');
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$cart = $session->get('cart', array());
$cart['items'][] = array('itemid' => $itemid, 'quan' => $quan);
$session->set('cart', $cart);
```

and I can get these products for displaying by using the code:

```
$cart_result = $session->get('cart');
$keys = array_keys($cart_result);
$tmp = array_values($cart_result);
$count = count(array_shift($tmp));
for ($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++) 
{
    $results = array();
    foreach ($keys as $key) 
    {
        $results[$key] = $cart_result[$key][$i];
    }
    foreach ($results as $result)
    {
        echo $result['itemid'];
        echo $result['quan'];
    }
}
```

That works perfectly. But I need to display the products as names and prices that are retrieved from the DB with quantities that are stored in the session. So in **mod_mymodule/helper.php** I need something like:

```
...
$ids = array();
foreach ($results as $result)
{
    $ids[] = $result['itemid'];
}
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('name','price')))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__products'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('id')." IN (".implode(',', $ids).")");
$db->setQuery($query);
$items = $db->loadObjectList();
```

and `return $items;` but including quantities i.e. with `$result['quan'];` and to display in **mod_mymodule/tmpl/default.php** like:

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    echo $item->name.$item->price.$item->quan;
}
```

Unfortunately, even when I display products without quantities by using the above query I get only the last product instead of all the products that are stored in the session. So I have two problems: I don't know how to display ALL the products and how to display them with quantities from the session.

Comment: Whats happens when you use `var_dump($ids);`?

Comment: If I use `$items = array();foreach ($results as $result){$items[] = $result['itemid'];}return $items;` in **helper.php** and use `var_dump($items);` in **tmpl/default.php** I get `array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" }`

Comment: So that's your answer. `2` is the **only** ID that is being returned by `$result['itemid']`, hence why your database query is only displaying 1 result

Comment: It was your solution by the link http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/9510/4042 and it really works if I **echo** IDs. But why does it not work if I **push them to array**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I resolved the first problem with the code:

```
$ids = array();
foreach($cart_result['items'] as $result) {
    $ids[] = $result['itemid'];
}
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('name','price')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__products'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('id')." IN (".implode(',', $ids).")");
$db->setQuery($query);
$items = $db->loadObjectList();
return $items;
```

Now the second problem regarding quantities remains

Comment: Since this update is not an "acceptable" answer, perhaps I can persuade you to remove this post and add this code block to your question as an edit, then explain the remaining issue so that Nagarjun and other volunteers can post something that is worthy of the green tick.

Comment: [Comment  bump ]

Answer (score 2):

Query: Fetch item id as well.

```
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'name','price')))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__products'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('id')." IN (".implode(',', $ids).")");
```

Loop: Loop over the items fetched and compare with array in session

```
foreach($items as $item) {

    foreach ($results as $result){

       if($item->id == $result['itemid'])
       {
          echo $item->name.$item->price.$result['quan'];
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But it's a module and I need to return $items only in **helper.php** and loop over the items only in **tmpl/default.php**. I created two methods in helper: one for passing $items and one for passing $results to tmpl. But any simpler or better way would be appreciated